# when [:punct:] is too much

Tags: regex, r

I'm cleaning text strings in R. I want to remove all the punctuation *except* apostrophes and hyphens. This means I can't use the `[:punct:]` character class (unless there's a way of saying `[:punct:] but not '-`).

`! " # $ % &  ( ) * + ,  . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _  { | } ~.` and backtick must come out.

For most of the above, escaping is not an issue.  But for square brackets, I'm really having issues.  Here's what I've tried:

```
gsub('[abc]', 'L', 'abcdef') #expected behaviour, shown as sanity check
# [1] "LLLdef"

gsub('[[]]', 'B', 'it[]') #only 1 substitution, ie [] treated as a single character
# [1] "itB"

gsub('[\[\]]', 'B', 'it[]') #single escape, errors as expected
```

> Error: '[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'[["

```
gsub('[\\[\\]]', 'B', 'it[]') #double escape, single substitution
# [1] "itB"

gsub('[\\]\\[]', 'B', 'it[]') #double escape, reversed order, NO substitution
# [1] "it[]"
```

I'd prefer not to used `fixed=TRUE` with `gsub` since that will prevent me from using a character class.  So, how do I include square brackets in a regex character class?

ETA additional trials:

```
gsub('[[\\]]', 'B', 'it[]') #double escape on closing ] only, single substitution
# [1] "itB"

gsub('[[\]]', 'B', 'it[]') #single escape on closing ] only, expected error
```

> Error: ']' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'[[]"

ETA: the single substitution was caused by not setting `perl=T` in my `gsub` calls.  ie:

```
gsub('[[\\]]', 'B', 'it[]', perl=T)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `[:punct:]`, when you combine it with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?!['-])[[:punct:]]
```

This way a `[:punct:]`is only matched, if it is not in `['-]`. The negative lookahead assertion `(?!['-])` ensures this condition. It failes when the next character is a `'` or a `-` and then the complete expression fails.

Comment: And to use that in R, you'd do `gsub("(?!['-])[[:punct:]]", "", x, perl=TRUE)` where `x <- "'-!#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_{|}~\\"`, for example.

Comment: Neat! And when I remembered to include `perl=T` in my `gsub` call it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a character class you only need to escape the closing square bracket:

Try using `'[[\\]]'` or `'[[\]]'` (I am not sure about escaping the backslash as I don't know R.)

See [this example](http://regexr.com?34pf6).

Comment: it appears that in R, this produces only a single substitution that treats `[]` as a pattern rather than a set of characters. I've updated my question to include this test.

Comment: ... and I've updated it again with a fix for that issue that allows your solution to work.